# Laravel ManyToMany Contains method issue

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, relationship

i have ManytoMany relationship between the models Article and Keywords, to avoid duplicate entry i have made (IF) statement test:

```
if(!$Article->keywords->contains($keyword1->id)){
                $Article->keywords()->attach($keyword1->id);
           }
```

The things make me crazy:
1- the first time the code runs perfect.
2- after i empty the database tables and test it again it's gives me this error:

```
    QueryException in Connection.php line 763:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '34-1' for key 'article_keyword_keyword_id_article_id_unique' (SQL: insert into `article_keyword` (`article_id`, `keyword_id`) values (1, 34))
```

when i tracked the error its appear that executing the line : `$Article->keywords()->attach($keyword1->id);` even when `if(!$Article->keywords->contains($keyword1->id))` gives false.

Here is the complete piece of code:

```
foreach ($ArticleKeywords as $keyword) //ArticleKeywords the keywords table come from the submitted form
        {

           if (keyword::whereTranslation('name', $keyword)->exists())
           {
               $keyword1 = keyword::whereTranslation('name', $keyword)->first();

               if(!$Article->keywords->contains($keyword1->id)){
                    $Article->keywords()->attach($keyword1->id);
               }


            }
            else
            {
                $keyword1 = new Keyword;
                //$data['lang'] was sent from the view to the controller post method
                $keyword1->translateOrNew($data['lang'])->name = $keyword;
                $keyword1->save();
                $user->keywords()->save($keyword1);


                $Article->keywords()->attach($keyword1->id);

            }


        }
```

Comment: Why are you not using the `sync()` method?

Comment: my problem isn't what i use, yes i agree sync is better, but what the problem in this statement `if(!$Article->keywords->contains($keyword1->id)){
                    $Article->keywords()->attach($keyword1->id);
               }` why isn't working

Comment: i just removed the duplicate values from the keywords array to solve current issue, but still can't understand the problem